# change of DATASET RECORD causes screen flicker in angular DATATABLES

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using angular datatables. I have used the ng-repeat to to render all the values on DOM.
Let say I am using products as my primary data collection and dummy products as secondary. I am using my primary data collection in ng-repeat.
I did some operations operation dummy data collection and assign the result set to the Primary data collection.
The datatable is reflected in the DOM but it causes screen flicker which looks bad.
Does any one know Why this is happening? Is this the Datatables releated issue or angularjs ng-repeat issue?

NOTE: My data collection has volume size of about 200+ records.

Comment: Hey Shankar, please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Add this class="table dataTable" to your base table.
Still this will flicker a bit. 
Problem here is the datatable is rewriting the dom, first making your default table visible and then binding the datatable ui.

During this time phase the default table you have set appears for a while and then the datatables plugin changes it to its UI.

You just need to replicate your table to look like the datatable ui plugin.